# How did Optimus Prime know that Sam was a spy?

Tags: transformers, dark-of-the-moon

In *Transformers:Dark of the Moon* where the US government decides that the Autobots should leave Planet Earth, Sam - driven by his weak human feelings - has a small bad robot hidden in his hand and asks Optimus Prime what the secret plan is to actually stay on Earth and fight the bad robots.

Optimus Prime actually has a plan (the Autobots hide in a rocket of the spaceship and eventually fall into the ocean before the spaceship leaves the atmosphere) for that and says that Sam is his friend, but he says to Sam that no, there is no such plan!

How did Optimus know that Sam was a spy?

Comment: which transformer film this question is about?

Comment: @AnkitSharma the one that all the Autobots are embarking on a human spaceship and are leaving earth (because USA told them to). The Megadron team takes the spaceship down - however the autobots have secretly escaped the ship before the assault. At that movie, I think that Sentinel Prime is an ally of Megadron.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps Optimus sensed the energon present in his vicinity. Or it might be the case the plan was only made for the autobots, optimus was unsure of putting his trust in the human race and thus decided not to divulge his secret plan to Sam to ensure their survival.

Comment: I want to believe the first. Sam was acting weird. Optimus didn't trust the humans, but trusted Sam in general, I believe.

Comment: @gsamaras Yes in the "revenge of the fallen" Ironhide was able to sense a decepticon nearby . there has to be some mechanism .

Comment: @gsamaras Lately i have been wondering why didn't bumblbee sensed the presence of that impostor woman decepticon in the movie : Revenge of the Fallen

Comment: He did! Don't you remember how he "peed" her while she was on the car? Well, on the other hand maybe he just did it because Sam had a gf, but in any case it was obvious that Bee didn't like her! ;)

Answer (score 5):

In the movie before the take-off, Sam said in his "last" conversation with Optimus that no "HUMANS" were listening. 
Indicating that the decepticons were listening and not triggering the decepticon watch around his wrist.